# not able to view the JSON format of the data after submitting the form

Tags: html, angular, forms, frontend, swagger

i am working on angular project where i have to fill the username and password
after submitting the code i have routed to swagger URL but i am not able to get the JSON format data

my form

```
<!-- HTML code for the login form -->
<form  #form="ngForm" id="login-form" (ngSubmit)="addUsers()">
  <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" [(ngModel)]="addUser.userName"><br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="addUser.userPassword"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

my typescript

```
addUsers(){
  this.userService.addUser(this.addUser)
.subscribe({
  next:()=>
  this.router.navigateByUrl("https://localhost:7068/Users")
})
```

even i added service too check this out
My service

```
addUser(adduser:User):Observable<User>{
  adduser.userName
  adduser.userPassword
  return this.http.post<User>(this.baseApiUrl+"/Users",adduser)
}
```

i even tried to route using new component too but i failed please help me out

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: **Always** some "not working": 1.- see if "compile", 2.-open the console (F12 in the navigator) to see if there're an error in console. The error is that you're write `addUser.userName; add.UserPassword`. So it's impossible your code "compile". Just remove this two lines. NOTE: **Don't write** lines that you don't understand, programming it's not "write words"

Comment: @Eliseo i even tried removing those lines but the its still not displaying the json format of the data...when I do that manually I am able to view the data...in json format
and to inform that....i wrote those lines by mistake... thanks for informing that I have removed it now...
and in console....i am not getting any error I think I have made some logic error I guess

Comment: It's looks like fine. Well you indicate to the http, (I imagine is HttpClient) that the **response** is of type<User> (but even it's not true, the post should be executed). Check if your API admit the url, you can check in navigator (F12) in NetWork, if the call is executed and the response. Sorry I don't know say you much :(